# Snippet inside snippet not rendering

Tags: snippets, snippet-sync

On a template I am calling in a series of snippets like so:

```
{sn-head}

{sn-header}

{sn-page}

{sn-listing-videos}

{sn-footer}
```

The `sn-listing-videos` snippet contains an entries loop like so:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="video" limit="12" paginate="both" disable="categories|member_data" dynamic="no"}

    {sn-listing-pagination}

    {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The `sn-listing-pagination` snippet isn't rendering in this instance. In fact, none of my snippets are rendered with the `sn-listing-videos` snippet at all.

I have a few other templates which contain listing snippets for other channels which contain the same code apart from the channel parameter in the exp:channel:entries tag - and the pagination snippet works just fine in these.

I am using the [SnippetSync](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/snippetssync) module. I have run a test after having uninstalled it, but still no luck.

What could cause this problem for that particular template/snippet?

=================

EDIT:

Here's the code for a different listings page where the same set up works.

Template code:

```
{sn-head}

{sn-header}

{sn-page}

{sn-listing-resource}

{sn-footer}
```

`sn-listing-resource` snippet code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="resource" limit="5" paginate="both" disable="categories|member_data" dynamic="no"}
    {sn-listing-pagination}

    {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

=================

EDIT #2:

Content of pagination snippet:

```
{paginate}
      <div class="listing-pagination">
          {pagination_links}
            {previous_page}
              <a href="{pagination_url}">Prev</a>
            {/previous_page}

            {page}
              <a href="{pagination_url}" {if current_page}class="active"{/if}>{pagination_page_number}</a>
            {/page}

            {next_page}
              <a href="{pagination_url}" class="button slim next">Next</a>
            {/next_page}
          {/pagination_links}
      </div>
{/paginate}
```

Comment: Also, can you post the snippet of `{sn-listing-pagination}`

Comment: Question, in your Videos channel, is there more than 12 entries?

Comment: There's two video entries. I've tried changing the limit to '1' to force pagination, but that didn't change anything :(

Comment: I would try adding more than 2 videos to the channel and then test on a `limit` higher than _1_

Comment: @Katrin, updated my answer below for you.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the parse order. EE parse snippets at a very early stage all at once, hence not being able to have a snippet within a snippet. I suggest removing the `{sn-listing-pageination}` and just hard code that in the `{sn-listing-videos}`.

Or you could convert all your snippets/variables over to [Low Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-variables) and set the `{sn-listing-pagination}` to a early parsed variable. This will then parse before the `{sn-listing-video}`

Comment: Feel free to check out this handy guide too! When I run into this issue I always  turn to the Low Parse Guide! http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf

Comment: I am aware of the parse order, I'm just not quite sure I understand the implications of this in this instance. You say you can't have a snippet within a snippet, but the same set up works in three other listing snippets. How's that possible?

Comment: Please post the working code in your question above. Most likely it's being used slightly different.

Comment: Done. I just copied and pasted the working code and changed the channel and limit parameters.

Comment: This isn't true. See my answer for a detailed explanation.

Comment: True, the only thing I was missing is that snippets are parsed in a linear sequence. So, like you mentioned the  pagination snippet needs to be created before the other snippets that contain it. However, my provided answer will work in this case

Comment: Your example will work, for sure. I should have clarified. Just the parsed "all at once" part is not true. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I was just able to accomplish what you're after using Snippet Sync AND **the problem (see below)**.

In EE template, I have just:

```
{sn:snippet_1}
```

In `sn:snippet_1`, I have:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="pages" limit="1" paginate="both" disable="categories|member_data" dynamic="no"}
  {sn:pagination}
  {title}<br>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

In `sn:pagination`, I have:

```
{paginate}
  <div class="listing-pagination">
      {pagination_links}
        {previous_page}
          <a href="{pagination_url}">Prev</a>
        {/previous_page}

        {page}
          <a href="{pagination_url}" {if current_page}class="active"{/if}>{pagination_page_number}</a>
        {/page}

        {next_page}
          <a href="{pagination_url}" class="button slim next">Next</a>
        {/next_page}
      {/pagination_links}
  </div>
{/paginate}
```

My output is:

```
<div class="listing-pagination">
  <a href="http://www.starterslab.local" class="active">1</a>
  <a href="http://www.starterslab.local/P1" >2</a>
  <a href="http://www.starterslab.local/P2" >3</a>
  <a href="http://www.starterslab.local/P1" class="button slim next">Next</a>
</div>

Inner Page

<div class="listing-pagination">
  <a href="http://www.starterslab.local" class="active">1</a>
  <a href="http://www.starterslab.local/P1" >2</a>
  <a href="http://www.starterslab.local/P2" >3</a>
  <a href="http://www.starterslab.local/P1" class="button slim next">Next</a>
</div>
```

**HOWEVER**, if I put my pagination code inside of `sn:snippet_1` and my channel entries code into `sn:pagination` I get this unparsed code:

```
{paginate}
  <div class="listing-pagination">
      {pagination_links}
        {previous_page}
          <a href="{pagination_url}">Prev</a>
        {/previous_page}

        {page}
          <a href="{pagination_url}" >{pagination_page_number}</a>
        {/page}

        {next_page}
          <a href="{pagination_url}" class="button slim next">Next</a>
        {/next_page}
      {/pagination_links}
  </div>
{/paginate}
```

**Here's why: Snippets are parsed in order among themselves. So, make sure your `sn-listing-pagination` snippet is listed after/below `sn-listing-videos` in EE. If not, create a new snippet for it so that it is parsed at the end.**

To further illustrate, below is a view of my exp_snippets table (not used the example above). Note the `snippet_id` column. Snippets are parsed in order, from 1 to whatever you have.

So, you can embed snippet id 7 into 1 and it will parse since 7 is parsed after 1. You can't do the reverse. When snippet 7 is parsed, if snippet 1's tag is embedded it will just come back unparsed, since snippet 1 has already been parsed. It won't know to re-parse it.

[image]

Comment: Now, I'm curious! Do you mind of explain a little better your conclusion?

Comment: Sure. I'll throw in some for you. :)

Comment: Wow! This is amazing, but we should talk to somebody at EllisLab if we can rely on this. Since it's undocumented, this can change without warning.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to test and explain this in such detail, I really appreciate that.

I have deleted the pagination snippet and created it again. I looked at the `exp_snippets` table and it had a higher ID (47) than the listing snippet (46), but that didn't change anything. I did realise that the video listing snippet had a `site_id` of `1` and all the others had a `site_id` of `0` - which is very odd and I assume a glitch from the SnippetSync add-on.

[Here's a screenshot of the table](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5JY_dmWbGnNMkxvSmNXNHFIUVU/edit?usp=drivesdk).

Comment: I have changed the `site_id` for all snippets to `1`, but I still cannot get the pagination to work. It also has now stopped working in the `sn-listing-news` snippet, which worked fine before. So there's something else going on and maybe it's not quite as straightforward...

Comment: Don't change `site_id`. Don't change anything in the database at all. Instead create a new snippet for your pagination code and then delete the original one.

Comment: I just asked EllisLab about this.

They don't have plans to change this behavior, but they don't recommend to rely on this unless you have a massively pressing need to nest snippets, due to the lack of official support.